# Evaluating boolean expression stored in string with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Currently I'm doing some integration testing for an app and such cases are stored in a json file, **the assert part of the unit test is also stored in that json**, so I need to parse that string to boolean or something.

I've tried with Roslyn but I can't make it work, it is throwing this exception:

> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException: (1,1): error CS0103: The name 'entry' does not exist in the current context

The json file with the case looks like this:

```
  "entries": [
    {
      "name": "SayHello",
      "request": {
        "text": "Hello",
        "id": "61hacck8j6jg"
      },
      "response": {
        "text": "Hello",
        "id": "47me557ikbf7"
      },
      "assert": "Entry.Request.Text == Entry.Response.Text"
    }
  ]
```

Tried with something like this:

```
object result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("entry.Request.Text == entry.Response.Text");
```

Tried with lowercase, uppercase, same style as the class created, still not working.

Solution source code for this is [here](https://github.com/emimontesdeoca/integration-test-directline-bot-framework), maybe you can get more information there.

**Edit:** the file where the code explained above is [here](https://github.com/emimontesdeoca/integration-test-directline-bot-framework/blob/master/src/IntegrationTestBotFramework/IntegrationTest.cs)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto edited, thank you.

Comment: You cannot interact directly with local variables like that; you must explicitly expose them to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work with a `Globals` class.

```
public class Globals
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ExpectedResponse
    /// </summary>
    public Activity Request;
    /// <summary>
    /// ReceivedResponse
    /// </summary>
    public Activity Response;
}
```

Then in the test you pass the parameters, kinda how @SLaks said in the comments:

```
/// Arrange
var globals = new Globals { Request = entry.Response, Response = latestResponse };

/// Assert
Assert.IsTrue(await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>(entry.Assert, globals: globals));
```

Hopefully this helps someone!